# jpa newly created entity does not appear in query

Tags: caching, jpa, eclipselink, java-ee-6

We are writing a java ee web app on top of weblogic 12c - 12.1.2

JPA 2.0

Eclipselink 2.4.2

shared-cache-mode is set to ALL in persistence.xml

One strange behavior is, newly created jpa entity is not seen by query even after transaction commits

I can see the changes in db but not in the list page

if I do  getEntityManager().getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evict(thisClass) then the list page gets data again, and shows the new entity

Comment: Are you referring to a reference to the entity from another entity, or an actual query not returning the new entity as a result?  Are you using a query result cache?

Comment: will work on creating small test project, so i can validate this for a simple test case, for now we have ugly clear cache stuff all over our controllers